# Error while installing curl

Tags: package-management, dependencies, curl

```
hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/hp writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for hp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.37.1-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ curl
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

I am getting different error

Comment: what should i do to remove above error plz help

Comment: What's the output of `apt install -f`?

Comment: hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/SL - VI/Assignment 5/assign5$ apt install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/SL - VI/Assignment 5/assign5$ sudo apt install -f
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/hp writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for hp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/SL - VI/Assignment 5/assign5$

Comment: @karel: But OP used `sudo` to run `apt-get`. The permission issues are related to something different.

Comment: @ajit: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Due to the specific package conflict I also suggest that you update the package data and upgrade all available packages: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -f`. If that fails please **[edit]** your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of that command sequence. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The command that generated the error was `$ apt install -f` (from the second comment posted by ajit). This is clearly not the same as what you claim it is.

Comment: @karel: `sudo: /var/lib/sudo/hp writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700` looks a lot like the message came from `sudo`. I don't see any other permission issue in the question. If you mean OP's comment, they posted the output of the same command *with* `sudo` immediately afterwards and before your comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75446/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-karel).